# How to require a relative path in PHP

Tags: php, relative-path, require

How can I PHP require a file using a relative path on a Linux server from inside a symbolic link?

I tried:

```
require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . "/app.config.php");
```

But that is throwing an error saying the file does not exist. Here is the file structure:

```
/srv/www/accounts/dev
   app => /srv/www/myapp
       index.php
   app.config.php
```

So `app` is a symbolic link to `/srv/www/myapp` but when I try and require `app.config.php` php get's confused and tries to require `/srv/www/myapp/app.config.php` instead of `/srv/www/accounts/dev/app.config.php`.

How is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Should be either `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: I've been trying to do this too. Without any luck. :'( answers would be good. Problem is that php tries to translate the linked path to the actual path.

Answer (score 1):

Try `require_once(__DIR__.'../app.config.php');`

Hope that works :)

Just a note, if you're on PHP < 5.3, try `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__` :)

Comment: See original question (updated), the problem appears to be because I am using a symbolic link.

Comment: Should be either `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: So this works, but its sloppy and hackie. Anyway to reduce this? `require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . "/../accounts/dev/app.config.php");`

Answer (score 0):

require_once(__DIR__."/../app.config.php");

Comment: Missing an ending quote there, and to be pedantic, you should use single quotes :)

Comment: Thanks for spotting the missing end quote - I fixed it.

Comment: See original question (updated), the problem appears to be because I am using a symbolic link.

Comment: See my comment on your original, unsure if it's a typo or what

Comment: So this works, but its sloppy and hackie. Anyway to reduce this? `require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . "/../accounts/dev/app.config.php");`

Answer (score 0):

i think its the way the folders are setup, if u have like the /srv/www/accounts/dev/app.config.php. is in a different folder then /srv/www/myapp/app.config.php

ones in /accounts/dev and the other is in /myapp

you dont want a relative path you want absolute, relative would only be in that folder you have to at least let it know which folder to check, so i think you wanna go to the a different folder

Answer (score 0):

You might try using realpath() to get the path. That is supposed to expand symbolic links and return the absolute path. Something like:

```
require_once(realpath('../') . "app.config.php");
```